# MongoDB Aggregation with Mongoose in Route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Messing around with aggregations in MongoDB in a Node / Express app with Mongoose.  Here's the route:

```
router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
    let movies;
    if(req.query.search){
        escapeRegex(req.query.search);
        const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    
        movies = await Movie.aggregate(
            [
                { '$match': {'title': regex} },
                { '$limit': 5 }
            ], (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(result)
                }
            }
    );

    console.log("Result:", movies);
    res.render("atlas/search", {movies: returnedMovies});

} else {
    Movie.find({}).sort('title').limit(10).exec((err, allMovies) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("atlas/search",{movies: allMovies});
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Essentially what I'm doing here is taking in user input from a search bar, then running that input through an aggregation; however, I'm unable to get any results (hits my 404 not found page) and nothing is returned to the console through any of my `console.log` attempts.  The `else` route, where if no search is present return the first 10 movies, works perfectly fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
escapeRegex(req.query.search);
const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
```

to

```
const regex = new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i');
```

this might help out

Answer (score 0):

To do a regex-based search, you need to use the operator `$regex` in your `$match` stage. Like this:

```
{ '$match': {'title': { $regex: regex } } }
```